# get xml attribute using CFSCRIPT

Tags: xml, coldfusion, xml-parsing

Simple XML

```
<employee> 
    <name EmpType="Regular"> 
        <first>Almanzo</first> 
        <last>Wilder</last> 
    </name> 
</employee>
```

I'm trying to use CFSCRIPT to test for the existence of the attribute "EmpType"

Tried using isDefined('_XMLDoc.employee.name[1].xmlAttributes.EmpType');
to no avail

Tried using  structkeyexists(_XMLDoc,'employee.name[1].xmlAttributes.EmpType'); 
to no avail

Any other thoughts?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I agree StructKeyExists is what you want change this:

```
structkeyexists(_XMLDoc,'employee.name[1].xmlAttributes.EmpType')
```

To this:

```
 structkeyexists(_XMLDoc.employee.name[1].xmlAttributes,'EmpType')
```

You want all but the last item you're checking for as the first argument.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<cfscript>
   employee.name[1].xmlAttributes["EmpType"]
</cfscript>
```

Comment: I tried this, but unfortunately, it doesn't find the existence of the attribute.

Answer (score 0):

I use CFSCRIPT to parse XML.

When you test for the existence of a node, you should use structKeyExists(); This requires two paramenters, the scope and the variable. The scope cannot be in quotes. The variable MUST be in quotes.

```
structKeyExists(SCOPE, "Variable");
```

Here's s short bit that might help.

```
// BOOTH NUMBER
BoothInfo.BoothNumber = ResponseNodes[i].BoothNumber.XmlText;
writeOutput("<h3>BoothNumber - #BoothInfo.BoothNumber# </h3>");

// CATEGORIES
if (structKeyExists(ResponseNodes[i].ProductCategories, "Category")) {
    Categories = ResponseNodes[i].ProductCategories.Category;
    CatIDList = "";
    for (j = 1; j lte arrayLen(Categories); j++) {
        CatID = ResponseNodes[i].ProductCategories.Category[j].XmlAttributes.ID;
        CatIDList = listAppend(CatIDList, CatID);
    }
BoothInfo.CatID = CatIDList;
} else {
BoothInfo.CatID = "";
}
writeOutput(BoothInfo.CatID);
```

Comment: I am not suggesting you use all of it. It just an example with a lot of possibilities.

Answer (score 0):

This was my solution:

```
myEmpType = '';
    try{
    myEmpType = _XMLDoc.employee.name[1].xmlAttributes["EmpType"]; 
} catch (Any e) {
    myEmpType = 'no category';
}
```

Comment: Wasn't that what I suggested?

Answer (score 0):

Use `xmlsearch`.

To test this, I added some more to your XML.

```
<employee> 
<name EmpType="Regular"> 
    <first>Almanzo</first> 
    <last>Wilder</last> 
</name>
<name> 
    <first>Luke</first> 
    <last>Skywalker</last> 
</name> 
</employee>
```

You'll notice that your original employee has the EmpType, but the second does not.

The code is a little verbose, but I just wanted to prove that it worked. It loops through each of the `name` nodes and checks to see if it has an `@EmpType` within it. If so, it dumps that XML node.

```
names = xmlsearch(testXML,'employee/name');
for(n=1;n<=arraylen(names);n=n+1){
    thisname = names[n];
    hasemptype = xmlsearch(thisname,'@EmpType');
    if(arraylen(hasemptype)==1){
        writedump(thisname);    
    }
}
```

There's good info about `xmlsearch` [here](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/827-Nylon-Technology-Presentation-Introduction-To-XPath-And-XmlSearch-In-ColdFusion.htm) and [here](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/1039-Ask-Ben-Iterating-Over-A-ColdFusion-XML-Document.htm).

Answer (score 0):

I would use XPath to take care of this:

```
XmlSearch(xmlObject, "//name[@EmpType]")
```

The expression above returns an array of nodes that have attribute EmpType, or an empty array if none found. So you can check if an array is empty. If you need just a boolean value, you can modify your xpath string like this:

```
XmlSearch(xmlObject, "exists(//name[@EmpType])")
```

This expression uses xpath function `exists()`, which returns true if any nodes with the attribute were found, or false if none. The entire expression returns either a true or a false, not an array like in the first case. The return type of `XmlSearch()` changes depending of what xpath expression returns.